# Convert mp3 to mp4 with album art

Tags: ffmpeg, batch-processing

I'm looking to convert mp3 files to mp4 for YouTube upload.
Currently using:

```
echo off
for %%a in ("*.mp3") do "F:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg" -loop 1 -i  "F:\ffmpeg\bin\input.jpg" -i "%%a" -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -tune stillimage -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=854:480 -c:a aac -shortest -strict experimental -b:a 192k -shortest "F:\ffmpeg\bin\Converted\%%~na.mp4"
pause
```

And it works fine. However, I'm trying to find the code that automatically gets the album art from the mp3 file itself rather than me providing it everytime. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Will the MP3 file always have artwork?

Comment: Not necessarily. Most of the time. Either way is fine.